# ELM QueryString parser dont compile

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am really trying to learn a bit of ELM, but my mind collapse at the query parse, my idea was to create a function to get a query string value by name something like: given an query string `?name=Neuber` a function like this `getParam "name"` that would return `Neuber`

But its failing at most basic example, it doesn't even compile

`page` comes [from here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/url/latest/Url-Parser-Query#map)

`routeParser` comes [from here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/url/latest/Url-Parser-Query#map2)

```
module Main exposing (..)
-- import Url.Parser exposing (Parser, (</>), (<?>), oneOf, s)
import Url.Parser.Query exposing (int, map, map2, string)

type alias QueryParams =
  { search : Maybe String
  , page : Maybe Int
  }


routeParser : Url.Parser.Query.Parser QueryParams
routeParser = map2 QueryParams (string "search") (int "page")

page : Url.Parser.Query.Parser Int
page = map (Result.withDefault 1) (int "page")
```

The error i got

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------- /a/long/way/to/project/src/Main.elm

The 2nd argument to `map` is not what I expect:

15| page = map (Result.withDefault 1) (int "page")
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
This `int` call produces:

    Url.Parser.Query.Parser (Maybe Int)

But `map` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    Url.Parser.Query.Parser (Result x number)

Hint: I always figure out the argument types from left to right. If an argument
is acceptable, I assume it is “correct” and move on. So the problem may actually
be in one of the previous arguments!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `int "page"` will return a `Maybe Int`, but you're trying to use it with `Result.withDefault`, which, as the error message says, expects a `Result`. The fix for this is just to use `Maybe.withDefault` instead.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, bu this is driven my crazy, these parses are to confusing for me, i would be glad if you can help me on the "sequence" of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264254/elm-get-query-parameter-as-string 
 thanks